# Why does kafka-client not provide the topic repartition function？

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to repartition my topic by using kafka-client, but kafka-client does not provide this function, does anyone know why not provide this function？

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Can you be clearer as to your question? Is it "how do I repartition"? Or are you literally asking why functionality doesn't exist?

Comment: emm，thank you ，i want to know why functionality doesn't exist in kafka-client